# Time complexity in traversed lists

Tags: time-complexity

Probably a simple qustion, but I'm a beginner, and find time complexity difficult.

What is the time complexeity when traversing n linked lists with, say, one hundred(100) elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the size of each list is limited by a constant number (e.g. every list contains no more than 100 elements), then the time complexity is *linear*: `O(n)`.

More generally, if the size of each list is limited by some function of `n`, say, `f(n)`, then the time complexity is `O(n*f(n))`.